# egl_emulation eglsurfaceattrib not implemented error in android application

Tags: android

I am getting  the following error in console logs:

```
egl_emulation eglsurfaceattrib not implemented
```

I am not able to see what I am drawing using Draw function.

I have tried changing manifest file, adding library. But no luck.

Comment: maybe more details would help us help you